# Excel crashing trying to set Activesheet.EnableCalculation = true

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel 2016 64 bit on Windows 10.  Excel keeps crashing when I try to set a worksheet to enable calculation like this:

ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True

So I wrote a test routine to try to capture the error description, but it would not go to the error handler, it just crash, so I cannot even get any detail.  The worksheet has a lot of formulae and it is unlock.  I also unlock other tabs where the formulae are sourcing the data in their calculation.  But it still would not let me set to true as the above line.  Any thoughts?  Much appreciated.

```
Sub test2()

   On Error GoTo Detail
   Debug.Print ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation  'this would tell me the current state, it is False.
   ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True       'at this line, it crashes

   Exit Sub

Detail:
   Debug.Print Err.Number
   Debug.Print Err.Description

End Sub
```

~G

Comment: What exactly are you aiming for with "ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation"?

Setting the calculation to manual might help you as well:
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

Comment: When you set `EnableCalculation = True` it recalculates the sheet. There might be an error in the sheet that isn't found until the calculation occurs. You could verify this theory by manually calculating the workbook. See if the crash happens there too.

Comment: _Excel keeps crashing_ isn't very informative. You've told us it doesn't go to the error handler, but what _does_ it do?

Comment: @Miwin, in the the activesheet, it has a formula in a cell which references a cell in worksheet(x).  That value in worksheet(x) is from a dropdown but in activesheet, it does not reflect the new value.  The formula in the activesheet cell is "=Summary!B20", but it is the old value, once the new value in worksheet(x) is selected from the dropdown, activesheet value does not change.  I check Excel does have automatic calcuation on.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your Locals window to see what your ActiveSheet is?
During your error DeBug and go the Locals window. Under Me there should be a ActiveSheet property.. If that is blank then you have no ActiveSheet and that's why there is an error.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, activesheet has a formula in a cell that reference another worksheet called 'Summary' for its' value.  That value is from a dropdown, which is from a data validation list.  The formula is like "=Summary!B20".  However, when the value in the dropdown changes, the cell in the activesheet does not update.  When I check EnableCalculation, by debug.print activesheet.enablecalculation, it comes out False.  I keep trying to set it to True, but I when I tried it crashes.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gerry you may try ActiveSheet.Calculate instead, to recalculate the Sheet. This should update the cells accordingly

Comment: @Gerry you could also try to change this value manually by selecting the required sheet and changing to the menu tab "Developer" -> "Properties" -> "EnableCalculation"

Comment: @gerry you should add that info into your Question

Comment: @miwin, that did it.  I went to properties and manually set EnableCalculation to True and immediately the value changed.   When I set it to True in the properties window, I was able to run through the code and then I went back to my code to change it to False and it also worked.  However, curiously, after my code set it to False and it ran through, I changed my code to see if I can set it to true, but it would not, it crashed again.   But at least I can set it manually in the properties window.  Thank you for your help and everyone who opined.